# Capture live streaming

Tags: video, flv, capture, packet, rtmp

I want to capture an RTMP stream. The videos are live, different every day and usually I can't tune in because I am busy at work doing something :(. I would like to capture the stream; however, they use anti-capturing techniques (it's live and free so I don't understand why). I tried Orbit Downloader without any luck. The URL seems kind of weird (judging by grab++). It has || in it and other URLs.

What applications can I use to capture this? I am open to using Linux.

Comment: i have a problem similar to yours, so what you got by using orbit downloader?

Comment: IIRC i either couldnt get orbit working or i couldnt get it working for the stream i wanted. I ended up using jaksta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jaksta](http://www.jaksta.com) for windows which can catch live streams.

Answer (score 3):

[Orbit Downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/) handle MMS, RTSP and RTMP protocols. With its Grab Pro module it let you inspect http to find the link to the streamed media. It's a freeware and a good Download Manager.

The firefox extension [Video Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/us/firefox/addon/3006) could help too

Answer (score 2):

For windows

I would suggest [Replay Media Catcher](http://www.applian.com/replay-media-catcher/demo.php) .its shareware

For linux

[rtmpdump](http://all-streaming-media.com/record-video-stream/rtmpdump-freeware-console-RTMP-downloading-application.htm) - freeware CLI application (Mac OS X, Linux, Windows). It allows you to dump RTMP streams onto your hard drive.

(or) 
Try here :http://all-streaming-media.com/faq/recording-media-stream/faq-record-download-capture-save-flash-flv-video-rtmp.htm

Answer (score 0):

whatever recorder you choose (VLC, rtmpdump, etc) you might want to use it via a front end I created called StreamRecorder.NET (shameless plug :) )

It's free and open source.. copied from the site:

- Records, joins and post processes stream using the tools you
  choose
- Full Command Line Interface (CLI) for
  scheduling and automation
- Keeps the recording process alive 
  (restarting when necessary)
- Time stamps file names to avoid
  overwrites
- Logs recorder output to file

http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamrecnet/

Answer (score 0):

[Streaming Video Downloader](http://www.binarymark.com/Products/StreamingVideoDownloader/default.aspx) can record RTMP. It's not freeware, but is far more convenient and easier to use than say RTMPDump. It works by monitoring Internet traffic for RTMP content and when it detects a new stream, it automatically saves it.

Disclosure: I am one of the authors.